# Is there any difference between X, and things which are X?

Tags: logic

My question is pretty much written in the title. By "different" I mean that they refer to two different logical groups?

For example, is there any difference between 'cars', and 'things which are cars'?

My logic class teacher is refusing to give me points because he thinks that there's a difference, and that I am totally wrong in referring for both of them as the same thing.

Comment: The question is quite unclear... It may refer to sets, in which case $X = \{ a,b,c, \}$ the "things which are (in) $X$" are different from the set $X$. Similar for a "concept" $X$ : individual horses are different from the general concept "horse".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes the question is about sets. But I want to say that this (in) you added is not part of the question. It's not about things in X and X itself, but using the exact same wording, 'X' and 'things which are 'X'? By 'things which are X', I mean the set that contains everything that X contains too.

Comment: If we are dealing with set theory, we must use the language of set theory. What does it mean "things which are $X$ ? Elements of set $X$ ? The fundamental relation of set theory are : $a \in X$, i.e. to be an *element* of $X$, and $Y \subseteq X$, i.e. $Y$ is a *subset* of $X$.

Comment: We didn't study set theory nor mentioned it in our class, but we were given general ideas and talks about 'sets', though they are definitely connected. "things which are X" means the collectives of all things that are elements of X. I really can't put it in other words.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I am looking for. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are dealing with set theory, we must use the language of set theory.

The fundamental relation of *set theory* is : $a ∈ X$, i.e. object $a$ is an element of *set* $X$. If $X= \{ a,b,c \}$ the "things which are (in) $X$" are its elements and they are different from the set $X$.

If with "things which are $X$" we mean the collection of all (and only) those things that are elements of $X$, due to the [Extensionality axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) this collection is the set $X$ itself.